# The Post Method is not supported for this route

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, post

Ya he solucionado el inconveniente de direccionamiento de la pagina edit, ahora me surge el problema que al presionar el botón de actualizar, me sale el siguiente mensaje:

```
"The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD."
```

y me sale en la siguiente ubicación:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\sisventas\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\RouteCollection.php
return (new Route('OPTIONS', $request->path(), function () use ($methods) {
    return new Response('', 200, ['Allow' => implode(',', $methods)]);
}))->bind($request);
}

$this->methodNotAllowed($methods, $request->method());
}

/**
* Throw a method not allowed HTTP exception.
*
* @param  array  $others
* @param  string  $method
* @return void
*
* @throws \Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException
*/

protected function methodNotAllowed(array $others, $method)
{
    throw new MethodNotAllowedHttpException(
        $others,
        sprintf(
            'The %s method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: %s.',
            $method,
            implode(', ', $others)
        )
    );
}

/**
* Get routes from the collection by method.
*
* @param  string|null  $method
* @return array
*/
```

Intenté utilizando el método `put` en la ruta `update` y lo mismo me tira el error.

Comment: sería mejor si pones el código de la ruta y desde donde la llamas. El error es porque haces un POST request a una ruta que solo soporta GET

Comment: _@porloscerrosΨ algo pude solucionar poniendo el method put.. pero ahora me sale el siguiente error_: 'View [almacen.categoria.show] not found.'

Comment: Bueno, ese es otro error. Si solucionaste lo que preguntas aquí, puedes escribir una respuesta de como "solucionar poniendo el method put", así queda para los que lean después. Luego hacer otra pregunta sobre lo que comentas.

Answer (score 2):

A este error lo pude solucionar poniendo el metodo put en la ruta y en el formulario de la siguiente manera:
En la ruta: colocar el put de la siguiente manera

```
Route::put('categoria/update','CategoriaController@update')-> name('categoria.update')
```

y en el formulario:

```
<form action=" {{ route('categoria.update', $categoria->idcategoria) }}" method="put">
```

Se reemplazo el metodo post por el metodo put.

Comment: Por favor no coloques como ejecutables fragmentos de código que involucran código o peticiones al backend, pues el *Stack Snnipet* solo es capaz de ejecutar: HTML+CSS+JS